# Classifying the singular point $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $f(z)=\frac{z-\frac{\pi}{2}}{1-\sin(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

> I am trying to find determine the type of singular point $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is  for the function,  $$f(z)=\frac{z-\frac{\pi}{2}}{1-\sin(z)}.$$

My attempt:

I originally thought that $$\lim_{z\to\frac{\pi}{2}} z-\frac{\pi}{2}$$ was a simple zero and that $$\lim_{z\to\frac{\pi}{2}} 1-\sin(z)$$ was also a simple zero. Hence $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a removable singularity. But the answer states that for $1-\sin(z)$, $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a zero of order $2$. How can this be?

**edit**

However, if I use the fact that $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a zero of order $k$ iff $$f(\frac{\pi}{2})=f'(\frac{\pi}{2})=..=f^{k-1}(\frac{\pi}{2})=0, \ \text{where} \ f^k(\frac{\pi}{2})\neq 0,$$ then $$f(\frac{\pi}{2})=1-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=0,$$
$$f'(\frac{\pi}{2})=-\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0,$$
$$f''(\frac{\pi}{2})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})\neq 0.$$
Hence $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a zero of order $k=2$ for $1-\sin(z)$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can instead study $g(z):=f(z+\frac\pi2)$ at $z=0$.

$$\begin{align}
g(z)&=
\frac{z}{1-\cos z}\\
&=\frac{z}{z^2+O(z^3)}\\
&=\frac{z}{z^2\left(1+\frac{O(z^3)}{z^2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}z(1+O(z))\qquad{(1)}\\
&=\frac{1}z+O(1)
\end{align}
$$
$(1)$: by geometric series.

Thus it is a simple pole with residue $1$.

---

To see why $\frac1{1-\sin z}$ has a pole of order two at $z=\frac\pi2$, we can instead look at the order of zero of $1-\sin z$ at $z=\frac\pi2$.

$$\sin z=\cos\left(z-\frac{\pi}2\right)=1-\left(z-\frac\pi2\right)^2+\cdots$$

Hence,
$$1-\sin z=\left(z-\frac\pi2\right)^2+\cdots$$

Obviously, that is a zero of order two, and its reciprocal will be a pole of order two.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is the way I calculated the order of the zero in my edit also correct?

Comment: @Bell Your method is indeed the same as mine (recall that the coefficients of Taylor series are derivatives of the function), so it is correct.

Comment: @Bell If you appreciate my work please kindly accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

By basic trigonometry $$ 1-\sin z=1-\cos (\pi /2 -z)=$$ $$=2\sin^2 ((\pi /2 -z)/2)= 2g(z)\cdot  ((\pi /2-z)/2)^2$$  where $\lim_{z\to \pi /2}\,g(z)=1.$... So when $\sin z \ne 1$ we have $$(\pi /2 -z)/(1-\sin z)=2g(z)/(\pi /2 -z).$$